# SpatVector to category SpatRaster

Tags: r, terra

I have a SpatVector object with lots of polygons and an attribute (column named "class") of type int, so that each polygon has its own class. I want to create a SpatRaster from that SpatVector so that each value on it is the class of the polygon it is inside. The polygons do not intersect. Pixels that are not inside a polygon should have a value of zero.

It seems I can accomplish that with lots of polygon filtering, lots of mask operations, than lots of merging, but there might be an easier way...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use sample data from `sf`, converted to `SpatVector`:

```
nc = st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf"))
nc = as(nc,"SpatVector")
```

First make an empty raster from `nc`:

```
ncgrid = rast(nc, nrow=200, ncol=200)
```

Choose your grid parameters to suit yourself there.

Now `rasterize` the vectors to that grid basis using the value of the "FIPS" column:

```
ncr = rasterize(nc, ncgrid, field="FIPS")
plot(ncr)
```

[image]

grid cells outside the polygons are `NA` at this point, so you can make them zero easily enough:

```
ncr[is.na(ncr)] = 0
plot(ncr)
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing to rasterize using "field" from library terra. Terra can read vector data from files, no need to use sf.

Comment: It is prettier to use argument `background=0` with `rasterize`, but a background 
of NA probably makes more sense, especially with a categorical raster.